# Is there any function to get an array value from string except `eval`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string `params`, whose value is `"1"` or `"['1','2','3','4']"`. By using `eval` method, I can get the result `1` or `[1,2,3,4]`, but I need the result `[1]` or `[1,2,3,4]`.

```
params[:city_id] = eval(params[:city_id])

scope :city, -> (params) { params[:city_id].present? ? where(city_id: (params[:city_id].is_a?(String) ? eval(params[:city_id]) : params[:city_id])) : all }
```

Here i don't want eval.

```
scope :city, -> (params) { params[:city_id].present? ? where(city_id: params[:city_id]) : all }

params[:city_id] #should be array values e.g [1] or [1,2,3,4] instead of string
```

Comment: Is it possible to correct the format in which you get your `city_id` params? If you have control of that, it sounds like this would be better fixed there.

Comment: Wait, that's rails params. Something really ugly must be happening in javascript-land to make rails see `"['1','2','3','4']"` in params. It is much easier to do the usual rails' thing for array parameters, which would not require eval.

Comment: Is `params` a regular old rails controller params? You definitely don't want to eval a query parameter like that, and I don't think you should need to (security concern)

Comment: sorry the params like this city_id = "[8, 1, 22, 25, 26, 2, 15, 10, 20, 23, 11, 18, 6, 24, 7, 12, 13, 9, 14, 21, 27, 17, 3, 16, 5, 4, 19]"

Comment: That will still be covered by my answer @RajkumarUlaganadhan :)

Comment: When sending params from an input or multiple input elements set the *name* attribute to `city_id[]`. Rails will convert the values automatically to an array under the name `param[:city_id]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've left a comment for what would be my preferred approach: it's unusual to get your params through as you are, and the ideal approach would be to address this. Using `eval` is definitely a no go - there are some big security concerns to doing so (e.g. imagine someone submitting `"City.delete_all"` as the param).

As a solution to your immediate problem, you can do this using a regex, scanning for digits:

```
str = "['1','2','3','4']"
str.scan(/\d+/)
# => ["1", "2", "3"]

str = '1'
str.scan(/\d+/)
# => ["1"]

# In your case:

params[:city_id].scan(/\d+/)
```

In very simple terms, this looks through the given string for any digits that are in there. Here's a simple Regex101 with results / an explanation: https://regex101.com/r/41yw9C/1.

Rails should take care of converting the fields in your subsequent query (`where(city_id: params[:city_id])`), though if you explictly want an array of integers, you can append the following (thanks @SergioTulentsev):

```
params[:city_id].scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)

# or in a single loop, though slightly less readable:
[].tap { |result| str.scan(/\d+/) { |match| result << match.to_i } }

# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Hope that's useful, let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: One needs to slap a `to_i` onto this, probably. Or maybe not (database might handle the type conversions)

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev - think Rails / DB will take care of this the bulk of the time, though I've added a note to cover this.

Comment: regex is pretty cool to extraction. @RajkumarUlaganadhan It will be great if you mark answer as accepted if above provide you sophisticated solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings look very close to JSON, so probably the safest thing you can do is parse the string as JSON. In fact:

```
JSON.parse("1") => 1
JSON.parse('["1","2","3","4"]') => ["1","2","3","4"]
```

Now your array uses single quotes. So I would suggest you to do:

```
Array(JSON.parse(string.gsub("'", '"'))).map(&:to_i)
```

So, replace the single quotes with doubles, parse as JSON, make sure it's wrapped in an array and convert possible strings in the array to integers.